# I need to check if time now is between two times

Tags: php, time

I need to check IF time is between two times with PHP I tried a lot of examples but they are not working for me, I guess I'm asking a stupid question but I'm not finding any answer.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('03:55:06');//start time
$datetime2 = new DateTime('11:55:06');//end time
```

I need to check IF current time is between $datetime1 and $datetime2.

IF is between { do something } ELSE { do somehting }.

Comment: If your date is greater than date 1, and your date is less than date 2, it's between them?  It should be as simple as that.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the dates cannot span across midnight e.g. between 10PM and 8AM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$start = new DateTime("11:59:59");
$end = new DateTime("13:59:59");
$now = new DateTime();

if($now < $end and $now > $start)
{
    echo "Yes, now is between start and end";
}
else 
{
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects of type DateTime have the special property that they can be compared directly.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('03:55:06');//start time
$datetime2 = new DateTime('11:55:06');//end time

$now = new DateTime('now');

if($now >= $datetime1 AND $now < $datetime2){
  echo 'Yes';
} else {
  echo 'No';
}
```